# Universal URL does not work when build is archived

Tags: ios, xcode, deep-linking

I think I implemented universal URL correctly and it is working fine when I launch the app directly from the Xcode but if I am archiving the build and sharing it via tesflight or [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) I am not able to open the app using URL scheme.

Comment: Could you elaborate it more?

Comment: @NirbhaySingh I  can open the app using configured Universal URL when I launch the app using Xcode in my Ipad. But when I am archiving it and installing in my Ipad through test flight or Diawi I can not open the app using configured Universal URL

Comment: @Abhijeet how did you resolve this issue? Any help?

Comment: Well I have answered it below. It has resolved my issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Associated Domains are in both entitlement files: "Debug" and "Release".
In my case all domains were listed in Entitlement-Debug.plist file but the Entitlement-Release.plist was empty.
After adding them manually to the 'Release' file - app installed via TestFlight started working with Universal Links.

Select All and Add your domain like this.

[image: Screenshot1]

Make sure you have both release and debug entitlements.

[image: Screenshot2]